# Unable to extract data using xpath within a script tag

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm trying to extract subscriber count of a channel using scrapy and I have figured out a script tag within which subscriber count is there but when I test it, I get black data. Please help.

```
split = '\"subscriberCountText\":{\"simpleText\"'
response.xpath("//script[contains(.,'" + split + "')]").extract()
```

You can search for the text `"subscriberCountText":{"simpleText"` within a channel's about source code page, but how do you extract that.

Comment: This looks like an `xy-Problem` to me - you might want to use a `json` (?) parser instead.

Comment: Can we have your input file html file?

Comment: check the source code : view-source:https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqwUrj10mAEsqezcItqvwEw/about

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the channel id in this [google_api](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UCqwUrj10mAEsqezcItqvwEw&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&key=AIzaSyAWpx46-G9ZByLe8Nk_wqtUekCXvTPM2oI)

and you will get all the information of this channel in json format.
 e.g your given chanels id is "UCqwUrj10mAEsqezcItqvwEw" you need to add this into "id" parameter of the api.Final URL will be "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UCqwUrj10mAEsqezcItqvwEw&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&key=AIzaSyAWpx46-G9ZByLe8Nk_wqtUekCXvTPM2oI"

Comment: I know this way.. the problem with the api method is the limitation of request. I need to make thousands of request, that's why i was looking for a crawling method. BTW thanks for adding the method to this thread.